# What causes Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property?

Tags: php, opencart

> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerProductProduct::$data has no effect in /home/user/public_html/example.com/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 57

Line 57: `$this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(`

Removing `$this` from `$this->data` rids the error.

I don't fully understand why taking the element out of the controller makes the code work as it should?

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using?

**PRE v2.0:** In this case changing the variable does not **"make the code work as it should*"** and you'll be missing your breadcrumbs. You should not change the variable - it should be left as `$this->data`.  You just need to initialize the property first like this:

```
$this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
```

Then afterward you can modify the array.  The product controller should already have that line so I'm assuming you've modified the core code.

**POST v2.0+:** The variable should indeed to `$data['breadcrumbs']` and not a class property. Again, it looks like someone has modified the core code and introduced this bug.

Try not to modify core code unless you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, the breadcrumbs are still there.  Strange they are when not supposed to be!  And yes, I am modifying the core code, it's not a live site.. just trying to learn. :)

Comment: If you want to learn about customizing Opencart my advice would be to learn vQmod.  It allows you to make non-permanent changes to various bits and makes debugging easier when you inevitably run into extension conflicts.